# a generic error occurred in gdi+

Tags: gdi+, reportviewer

I'm receiving "a generic error occurred in gdi+" processing error while
running a preview of my report inside visual studio.

When I have not designed the report at that time there was no error!
but when I have designed it completely it gives that error.

Comment: Could you post code/the report?

Comment: It might be a permissions issue, see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781390/saving-an-image-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a permissions issue as Babak suggested then it can also be a file name issue (check nothing is being saved to disk with illegal characters in the file name e.g. / etc.