# C# Save image (byte[]) via Webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Im trying to make a webservice that can accept a byte[] of an image, and save that to the webserver.
The code consists of two parts, the client that sends the data- and the webservice that gets the data.
Im getting the following error when trying to upload an image:
**System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: A generic error occurred in GDI+.**

myImage is a System.Drawing image.

```
private byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

using (Something.ClientServiceClient client = new Something.ClientServiceClient())
            {
                client.Open();
                client.uploadScreenShot(imageToByteArray(myImage));
            }
```

The webservice looks as follows:

```
public void uploadHofScreen( byte[] imgArray)
    {
        Image nImg = byteArrayToImage(imgArray);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(nImg);
        saveJpeg("/1/test.jpg", bitmap, 85L);
    }


private void saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality)
    {
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = getEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        if (jpegCodec == null)
            return;
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        img.Save("XXXX" + path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];
        return null;
    }
```

Both the webconfig and the appconfig has the following readerQuotas:

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Any advice what the issue is?

Comment: The problem is not in WCF. Debug the image processing to get a more detailed error.

Comment: You're sure this is not a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781390/saving-an-image-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi?rq=1)?

Comment: How does your `byteArrayToImage` look like?

Comment: Jeroen - I did look there for some of the code for the saving of the file yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

(Just fiddled a little with the permission on the upload folder and noticed that IIS did NOT have write permissions - sorry, I should have checked that before going here)

On the bright side, now you can see how you can upload an image via a webservice. :)

Comment: If the webservice we will be public it is better to send chunks of data than to increase readerquota's. It is low by default because of security issues.